# Strapi (CMS) - How to Configure to work with multiple Databases/Collections

Tags: mongodb, content-management-system, strapi

Is there a way to have Strapi CMS work with multiple databases?

In my case I'm using MongoDB, so it would be good if collection "A" was saved in one MongoDB Collection and then collection "B" was saved in a different MongoDB Collection.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I would like to know about this too.

Couldn't find a solution for this